# Check if image is white; if so make transparent

Tags: php, transparency, gd

I have an image, and I want to make it transparent if it's completely white. I have the following code already for GD for getting a part of the image:

```
$srcp = imagecreatefrompng("../images/".$_GET['b'].".png");
$destp = imagecreate(150, 150);
imagecopyresampled($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 40, 8, 150, 150, 8, 8);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($destp);
```

But how can I have it first check if the image is completely white, if so change it to transparent, and apply that to `$destp`?

Comment: You got three answers two of which are way better than mine but valid none the less, why don't you accept one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Based on re-reading the question, and the discussion below, I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
$width = 150;
$height = 150;

$srcp = imagecreatefrompng("../images/".$_GET['b'].".png");
$destp = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 150);

$white = 0;

for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
{
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
    {
        $currentColor = imagecolorat($srcp, $x, $y);
        $colorParts = imagecolorsforindex($srcp, $currentColor);

        if (($colorParts['red'] == 255 &&
            $colorParts['green'] == 255 &&
            $colorParts['blue'] == 255))
        {
            $white++;
        }
    }
}

if ($white == ($width * $height))
{
    imagecopyresampled($destp, $srcp, 0, 0, 40, 8, 150, 150, 8, 8);
}
else
{
    imagesavealpha($destp, true);
    imagefill($destp, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($destp, 0, 0, 0, 127));
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($destp);
```

This produces a blank image if the original image's 8x8 slice is all white, otherwise it resamples the 8x8 slice to 150x150.

---

**Original:**

I haven't ever done anything with PHP GD before, and thought it would be a fun challenge. Here's how I ended up making this happen:

```
$filename = 'test.png'; // input image
$image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);

// grab the input image's size
$size = getimagesize($filename);
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];

$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// make sure that the image will retain alpha when saved
imagesavealpha($newImage, true);
// fill with transparent pixels first or else you'll
// get black instead of transparent
imagefill($newImage, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($newImage, 0, 0, 0, 127));

// loop through all the pixels
for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++)
{
    for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++)
    {
        // get the current pixel's colour
        $currentColor = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);

        // then break it into easily parsed bits
        $colorParts = imagecolorsforindex($image, $currentColor);

        // if it's NOT white
        if (!($colorParts['red'] == 255 &&
            $colorParts['green'] == 255 &&
            $colorParts['blue'] == 255))
        {
            // then keep the same colour
            imagesetpixel($newImage, $x, $y, $currentColor);
        }
    }
}

// final output, the second arg is the filename
imagepng($newImage, 'newImage.png');
```

It allowed me to turn this:

[image: Test image before processing]

Into this (hard to see the alpha here, but you can open it to see):

[image: Image after processing]

Comment: Could you implement my code you see in my question? i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: It takes a certain part of the image and enlarges it. But could you include it?

Comment: Oops, sorry -- yes, I mixed up the source and destination arguments. Still, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. You want the enlarged bit -- from 8x8px to 150x150px -- to be transparent only if the original 8x8px image was all white? Do you want any part transparent if it's not all white?

Comment: You want the enlarged bit -- from 8x8px to 150x150px -- to be transparent only if the original 8x8px image was all white? - No. Only the part that i have taken from the original image.

Comment: Ok. Let me try asking this a different way. If the 8x8 part of the original image is all white, then it should be made transparent, correct? (ie. it basically shouldn't be added to the other image). What if it's NOT all white? Should the white bits still be made transparent, or should it be added to the image as-is? For example, if there's a red dot on a white background, should the background still be white after it's put on the image?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4292/discussion-between-gavin-anderegg-and-gdscei)

Comment: Yes, the image should not be changed to transparent if any pixel of it is a different color than white.

Comment: I've modified the answer above to reflect this. Also, I've opened a chat for further discussion.

Comment: Please check the discussion, where I state that it will just create a white image

Comment: The image created when I visit http://craffy.gdscei.com/devm/ppic.php?b=gdscei is transparent. It's just on a white background. See my comments in chat.

Comment: Please check the chat, I've given comments on it.

Comment: gdscei: It's clear that I've solved the question you had originally. If you'd like help with a new question, please create a new one. I'm considering this question resolved.

Answer (score 0):

A simple strightforward solution would be to use [imagecolorat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) and iterate through all the pixels of the png and if all are white change it to transparent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look through the GD manual pages, I think that the following should work for you (it did on my test server, anyway):

```
<?php
// Create image instance
$im = imagecreatefromgif('test.gif');
if (imagecolorstotal($im) == 1) {

    $rgb = imagecolorat($im, 1, 1); // feel free to test any pixel, but if they're all
                                    // the same colour, then it shouldn't really matter
    $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);

    if ($colors['red'] == 255 && $colors['green'] == 255 && $colors['blue'] == 255) {
        // I'm ignoring $colors['alpha'] but that's optional.
        echo "Yup; it's white...";
    }
} else {
    // if you've got more than one colour then the image has to be at least
    // two colours, so not really worth checking if any pixels are white
}

// Free image
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

References:

- [`imagecolorat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php).
- [`imagecolorstotal()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorstotal.php).